# Split the string using string delimiter and display the data along with delimiter

Tags: python, split

I need to get the string list along with delimiter
For example

`string= "I am a developer and i need to work on web development"`

I am using

````
re.split("and", string)```

I need to get Output as
**Output**
```I am developer 
and i need to work on web development```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using the [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function:

```
string = "I am a developer and I need to work on web development"
delimiter = "and"

string_1, string_2 = string.split(delimiter, maxsplit=1)
string_2 = f"{delimiter}{string_2}" # or string_2 = delimiter + string_2

print(string_1) # I am a developer 
print(string_2) # and I need to work on web development
```

This clearly relies on the fact that the delimiter **is** in the string.

Comment: What about when the delimiter isn't actually present?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> s = "I am a developer and i need to work on web development"
>>> s1 = s.replace('and', '\nand')
>>> s1
'I am a developer \nand i need to work on web development'
>>> print(s1)
I am a developer 
and i need to work on web development
>>>
```